# Read the latest S3 parquet files partitioned by date key using Polars

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-s3, parquet, python-polars

I have parquet files stored in s3 location which are partitioned by date key. Using Polars, i need to read the parquet file(s) from the latest date key folder. Here is an example of my s3 structure:

Amazon S3>Buckets>Bucket name>dev/>target/>refined/>STUDENTS.parquet/

Under **STUDENTS.parquet**, there are several folders partitioned by DATE_KEY i.e.,

[image]

Each of these folders contain parquet file(s).

Using Polars, i need to read the parquet file from the latest date key folder (DATE_KEY=2024-03-06/ in this example) into a Polars dataframe.

Do you think doing a descending sort on Name folder would be a way to achieve this?

Can someone please help me on his as i'm after Polars dataframe and not Pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two ways to achieve this.

1. Scan the entire dataset into a LazyFrame and filter on the fly.
2. Read the names of the folders in S3 and scan only the parquet files within the folder with latest date.

#### Option 1. Scan entire dataset into a `pl.LazyFrame` and filter on the fly.

```py
import boto3
import polars as pl

# 
profile = "your-profile"
s3_path = "s3://path/to/your/dataset/*/*.parquet"

# create session and obtain credentials
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=profile)
credentials = session.get_credentials().get_frozen_credentials()

df = (
    # scan entire dataset
    pl.scan_parquet(
        s3_path,
        storage_options={  
            "aws_access_key_id": credentials.access_key,
            "aws_secret_access_key": credentials.secret_key,
            "aws_session_token": credentials.token,
            "aws_region": session.region_name,
        },
    )
    # filter for latest partition
    .filter(
        pl.col("DATE_KEY") == pl.col("DATE_KEY").max()
    )
    .collect()
)
```

#### Option 2. Obtain name of latest partition folder and read only corresponding data.

```py
import polars as pl
import boto3
import os

# 
profile = "your-profile"
s3_bucket = 'bucket-name'
s3_prefix = "path/to/dataset"

# create session and obtain credentials
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=profile)
credentials = session.get_credentials().get_frozen_credentials()

# get path of latest partition
response = session.client("s3").list_objects_v2(Bucket=s3_bucket, Prefix=s3_prefix, Delimiter='/')
s3_prefix_latest = max(prefix["Prefix"] for prefix in response["CommonPrefixes"])
s3_path_latest = os.path.join("s3://", s3_bucket, s3_prefix_latest, "*.parquet")

# read data only from latest partition
df = pl.read_parquet(
    s3_path_latest,
    storage_options={  
        "aws_access_key_id": credentials.access_key,
        "aws_secret_access_key": credentials.secret_key,
        "aws_session_token": credentials.token,
        "aws_region": session.region_name,
    },
)
```

Comment: I went with Option 2 and it works perfectly - thanks @Hericks. Also if i need to do the same thing i.e., read parquet files with latest date key from a HDFS cluster instead of S3 bucket using Polars dataframe, how do i do it? Can you please help me.

Comment: @BalajiVenkatachalam Glad it helped! I have not worked with HDFS in the past. I'd suggest looking [here](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/2818) and opening a new question if it doesn't answer your question.